# How to finish this simple proof involving booleans

Tags: boolean, coq, proof

This is my progress on an exercise from here: https://github.com/userhr/MIT-6.826-2017

```
(** **** Exercise: 2 stars (andb_true_elim2)  *)
(** Prove the following claim, marking cases (and subcases) with
    bullets when you use [destruct]. *)

Theorem andb_true_elim2 : forall b c : bool,
  andb b c = true -> c = true.
Proof.
  intros c.
  (** Prove anything && false == false. *)
  assert (forall x : bool, andb x false = false) as H.
  destruct x. 
   -reflexivity.
   -reflexivity.
   (** Obviously true at this point since we have shown that no 
       matter what, andb b c will be false if one of them is 
       false. My idea is to use H to show that if it is to be 
       true, than both arguments must be true.
   *)
Qed.
```

The reason why I felt it's necessary to show that `(forall x : bool, andb x false = false)` is because I can't figure out how to do the obvious proof by proving that `(forall a b : bool, andb a b = true -> a = true, b = true)`

Comment: You are complicating your life too much. Recall two basic facts: andb is a function and it will compute (for example `andb true b` reduces to `b`; second, booleans are well suited to case analysis.

Comment: This is an exercise from the Software Foundations text book. As the file you linked says, we ask people to refrain from distributing solutions to exercises online.

Answer (score 0):

Code snippet for this is

```
Theorem andb_true_elim2 : forall b c : bool,
  andb b c = true -> c = true.
Proof.
  intros b c H.
  destruct c.
  Case "c = true".
    reflexivity.
  Case "c = false".
    rewrite <- H.
  destruct b.
  SCase "b = true".
    reflexivity.
  SCase "b = false".
    reflexivity.
Qed.
```